# How can I batch edit "date taken" metadata for AVI, MOV, MP4, etc. video files?

Tags: video, command-line, metadata, batch-processing, amazon-clouddrive

**BACKGROUND**

I just uploaded years of videos to Amazon Cloud Drive (consumer photo/video storage) and it is not recognizing when the videos were actually taken. I have all of these files categorized with directories for each year and within the year, a directory for each month.

```
i.e. ➞
/2009/01
/2009/02
...
/2012/03
/2014/04
... etc.
```

I tried the following command and it did adjust the "Created Date" to the proper day, month, and year for all the AVI files in the targeted directory!

```
SetFile -d "01/01/09 12:00" /Volumes/7TB\ WD\ External/Pictures/All\ Pictures/2009/01/*.AVI
```

Unfortunately, when I uploaded to my Amazon Cloud drive, that field does not seem to be what Amazon is using to determine the creation date/time of a video.

**MAIN QUESTIONS**

1. What field does Amazon Photos look at (in video files) to index the date/time of when a video was taken, so that I can view them in line with the year/month where they belong, instead of their own folder called "no date"?
2. Is there a tool or a command line script that I could write, similar to the command above, where I could bulk target the proper field and update the metadata for these video files with a "date taken" field that Amazon would be reading from?

If you have an amazon prime account, you can tinker with uploading Amazon photos and seeing if the metadata is working, [here](https://www.amazon.com/photos).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!